can I not use ~ when specifying a path using the cp terminal prompt?
I ran this in the git bash terminal: cp 06-Stu_HTML/ ~/sandboxes/bootcamp/01-sb
and got this error message: cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '06-Stu_HTML/'
I tried to look up the -r flag in correlation with using the cp prompt, but I couldn't find anything on it. Aside from that, I was wondering if trying to use ~ when designating a path was the reason I'm encountering issues?

From the cp man page "-R, -r, --recursive  copy directories recursively" In short, to copy directories, you need to specify a version of this option, most commonly -r.

Can you try this : cp -r 06-Stu_HTML/ ~/sandboxes/bootcamp/01-sb

when in doubt about the meaning of a command flag, type man [command], so man cp in this case to learn more.

cp by default does not copy directories. You did not specify what OS you are using. MacOS (using BSD cp) explains in its man-page, that it copies only files. Linux (using GNU cp) has the same restriction, but the man-page is IMO a bit misleading, as it does not explain this. Since the file tree below a directory is potentially very large, it is considered a bit dangerous to blindly copy everything. That's why you need to specify -R. GNU's cp also permits -r as synonym for this, but I suggest to use -R for portability.

@user1934428 Git Bash is a Windows application that provides Unix based shell experience for Git command line.

@Evert Unfortunately, it doesn't look like man works from Git Bash! I just see bash: man: command not found

@phuzi : Right, I missed the OPs information that he uses Git-bash. I have never worked with Git-bash; always used on Windows Cygwin, so I never had to worry about a missing man-page. If I were forced to use Git-bash, I guess I would use the man pages found online. If we google for man cp, we  find something useful; just have to pay attention, that we don't accidentally pick a page about BSD cp.

Thank you guys for the insight, I will need to do more research on what -R and. -r, recursive means exactly, as I've gotten by with avoiding learning some of the flags and have only recently began to really learn them. I'll also try out the man usage as a way to learn a little more about flags when I see them come up.  I can try just in the regular terminal shell as well, and also with my mac if gitbash won't let me use man ^.^ thanks phuzi, evert, and user#####
